# How to emulate cd-disk in CD-ROM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, emulation, cd-rom

I have a special product for working with data. I should emulate disk in cd-rom somehow on virtual machine Actually, I just need to have some files when I open CD-ROM in file explorer.

Comment: What is the minimum OS and what format is the disk image in. If it is Windows 8 or newer and .iso there are API's built in to windows you can use.

Comment: Windows 8 is OK for me. I can create such machine on esx server. Can you please describe your approach?